# Angular $resource response prototype

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am some what new to Angular 1.x and have a question about the response object I receive back from $resource.  The server side is returning a JSON array.   When I inspect the response I notice each of my elements have a prototype with the following Angular functions:

$delete, $get, $query, $remove, $save, $send

Why does $http add this extra functionality to my JSON response?   Is there any harm with removing them?

```
            var request = $resource(action.url, {}, {send: {method: action.method,
                        isArray: action.isArray ? action.isArray : false,
                        headers: action.requireToken ? {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + User.token} : '',
                        withCredentials: true}});
```

Comment: That is because you are using `$resource`

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @PankajParkar your right I'm using $resource.   Why does $resource do this?

Comment: Oh I think I got it now.  I looked at this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/EyalV/02-http-resource.  I see with $resource you can easily modify resources once a collection has been retrieved.

Comment: If you don't want these methods added, you can just implement the $http calls yourself. You will get JSON data which will be automatically converted to JS objects.